# Why use JSON instead of JS objects?

Tags: json

This may sound like a stupid question but:
Why do we use JSON for sending and receiving data? Why aren't js files used instead through which we won't even have to worry about the format of data. We will be able to send direct js objects instead of stringifying and parsing them every time.

Comment: JSON == JavaScript Object Notation == JS objects

Comment: JavaScript files still need to be parsed. I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply: if you use a text format such as JSON (or XML for that matter) it doesn't matter what languages are used by the programs exchanging the data. If you sent JavaScript code, you'd have to be able to use JavaScript to interpret it when you received it. By just using a notation format, JSON data can be exchanged between two programs completely unrelated to JavaScript the language.

P.S. JSON happens to be defined as a subset of the syntax which can be used to declare objects in JavaScript. If you sent JavaScript *code* you'd still have to worry about the format of the data or information - it still needs to be correct and parseable (as JavaScript, in that instance).

That would be true no matter what data format you choose, so I'm not quite sure I understand your concern from that perspective. But in general, what gets exchanged between programs is always *data* and not *code*.